# ehcache configuration file outside of classpath

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I need to be able to read an ehcache configuration file ( ehcache.xml) from outside the classpath to be able to have differents files by environment (to be able for example to change the multicast adress for cache sharing).

Before I was simply using an XML defined bean :

`<bean id="ehCache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="#{ 
         @PreferenceService.getEhcacheFileName() }" />
</bean>`

PreferenceService.getEhcacheFileName() send back a path in a properties file.

if the propertie is filled with a classpath path (classpath:ehcache.xml), the application work properly.

But if I want to use an absolute path (/home/foo/ehcache.xml) the resource is not found.

Is it possible to use an absolute path ? And if yes what properties do I need to use ?

Comment: whcih ehcache version ? spring version ? what the exact path you tried ? prefixed with file:/ ?

Comment: haha I forgot the "file:" in my path, thanks ! I don't think I can delete my question, so I will answer it.

Comment: to solve the issue of adapting the configuration to different environments (for example disable the distributed persistence in devel) I preferred to modify it programmatically when the application boots-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

configLocation can contain an absolute path without any trouble.

I just forgot to add the file: in front of the path in my properties file.

So my path is now : "file:/foo/foo/ehcache.xml"

Comment: you can accept your own answer as the "official / best" answer (green tick)